# In a pandas dataframe, how do I make a new column that is populated by values from a different row?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have three columns, "Date", "Name" and "Value" in my dataframe df.

"Date" and "Name" combinations are unique, i.e., no two rows have the same date-name combination.

I want to create a new column ("Yesterday Value") which is populated by the "Value" for a particular "Name" from the day before the row in question (please assume the dataframe isn't ordered in any way).

As a start, I have managed to create a column "Yesterday Date" using:

```
from datetime import timedelta

delta = timedelta(days=-1)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df["Yesterday Date"] = df(lambda x: x["Date"] + delta, axis=1)
```

Beyond this, I am pretty much stuck. I have tried using the apply method but haven't been able to figure out how to use it. I suspect the correct solution will require some kind of ordering followed by calling the shift method but I am getting confused because the "Date" column isn't full of just unique values (as it is the date and name combination that is unique). Perhaps some sort of group function is needed here but I am very much out of my depth there.

Just to clarify, for a given row, the solution should read the date and name, calculate yesterday's date and fill in the new column with the value corresponding to the name and yesterday's date.

Comment: You may find success using [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html?highlight=shift#pandas.Series.shift). Like this: `df['Yesterday Date'] = df.date.shift(1)`

Comment: @owen thanks, I've managed to create the "Yesterday Date" column already but can't figure out how to create the "Yesterday Value" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a DataFrame, which is **ordered by dates for each name**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[datetime.date(2022, 10, 10), datetime.date(2022, 10, 11)]*2,
              'name':['a','a','b','b'],
              'value':[1.,2.,3.,4.]})
```

```
    date        name    value
0   2022-10-10  a   1.0
1   2022-10-11  a   2.0
2   2022-10-10  b   3.0
3   2022-10-11  b   4.0
```

You could group by name and shift:

```
df['last_value'] = df.groupby(['name'])['value'].shift(1)
```

```
    date        name    value   last_value
0   2022-10-10  a   1.0         NaN
1   2022-10-11  a   2.0         1.0
2   2022-10-10  b   3.0         NaN
3   2022-10-11  b   4.0         3.0
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked like a charm! I had to first sort by date of course but, other than that, it worked perfectly.